# Sequentially run multiple bash scripts

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

sorry if this question has already been asked. I simply couldn't figure out right vocabulary to search for it. I have multiple experiments that I need to run in a cluster with GPU. But for now I start one job and wait for it to finish before launching the other. What can I do to "give command" to run all the scripts sequentially? I have something like the following:

```
./experiment.sh configs/job1.sh --train <gpu-ID>
./experiment.sh configs/job2.sh --train <gpu-ID>
./experiment.sh configs/job2.sh --train <gpu-ID>
```

where for `<gpu-ID>` I put `0` or `1` for specific GPUs

Right now I start a job say:

```
./experiment.sh configs/job1.sh --train <gpu-ID>
```

And periodically check whether it finished so that I can start `job2`.

What's a more efficient way to automate this?

Comment: try `&&` like `cmd1 && cmd2` , this means, cmd2 will run after cmd1 fineshed sucessfully

Comment: This *will* run the jobs sequentially; when `job1.sh` finishes, `job2.sh` will start.

Comment: Can you please confirm that you have tried running the code you posted, and that you have found that it fails to do what you ask for?

Comment: Asked and answered *ad nauseam*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have *would* run the jobs sequentially, if they appeared in a script:

```
$ cat all_jobs
./experiment.sh configs/job1.sh --train <gpu-ID>
./experiment.sh configs/job2.sh --train <gpu-ID>
./experiment.sh configs/job2.sh --train <gpu-ID>
$ sh all_jobs  # Runs job1, then run job2, then run job 3
```

If you want to run them from a single command line, separate them with `;`:

```
$ ./experiment.sh configs/job1.sh --train <gpu-ID>; ./experiment.sh configs/job1.sh --train <gpu-ID>; ./experiment.sh configs/job1.sh --train <gpu-ID>;
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use double amperstands : `script1 && script2 && script3`

In this example, `script2` will be executed when `script1` ends, only if `script1` returns 0, ie doesn't fail